# Package Issues with Drools drl file

Tags: drools, rule-engine

I do not understand why Drools cannot load my orders.drl file. I have a package declaration at the top of the file.  Here is the file:

```
   package innovision.org
   rule 'Find orders in product categories'
   when 
      exists Order()
   then
     System.out.println("Order exists!");
```

The error is:

File 'orders.drl' is in folder '' but declares package 'innovision.org'. It is advised to have a correspondance between package and folder names.

I first put the file in src/main/resources.  When it complained about this, I moved it to / src/main/resources/innovision/org/orders.drl.  This made the situation worse. It could not find the file.

Should my Java classes, follow the same package pattern of the rules file? I see examples which do that. I do not understand how Drools packages work and there is very little I could find defining this. Could someone explain how packages work and how to structure projects?  Thank you in advance.

How should the KieSession be created when using packages?

Here is my approach,to load the file:

```
//String rulePath = "src/main/resources/innovision/org/orders.drl" does not 
                                                //  work
    //String rulePath = "orders.drl" // loads the file but I get the message 
    // , I mentioned

    Resource resource = kieServices.getResources()
                       .newFileSystemResource(new 
           File(rulePath)).setResourceType(ResourceType.DRL);
```

Comment: Moving the DRL to `src/main/resources/innovision/org` should have solved your issue. What do you mean by "It could not find the file."?

Comment: When I placed in that package Drools reported it could not find the file: I then placed it in src/main/resources to get it to work